# Why xls opens while/after reading it from code?

Tags: c#, windows, excel, parsing

I have tool for parsing excel files. User chooses the xls/xlsx to be read, then my tool creates a copy of it in the temp with a random name, then actually parses the copy. The relevant part of the code:

```
string sourceFile = textBox1.Text;
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName();
string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileName + ".xlsx");
System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(destFile);
OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + destFile + "; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");
string qText = @"select * from [sheet1$]";
OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand(qText, cnn);
cnn.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(dt);
cnn.Close();
```

And then I start to work with the `DataTable`.
In case the original source files (not the copy) is open in excel, then the copy from the temp folder also opens up in excel. And here comes the strangest stuff. If it's closed during the script run, and then I open the original xls only from windows explorer, the copy from temp opens up again. Moreover, if I run the script e.g. 10 times (while original is closed), when I open it, all the 10 randomly named copies open up along with it. I suppose it's not due to the code itself, but some windows/office bug/feature.
Please advise.

Comment: What is the purpose of the two Interop instances declared and initialized? Remove them if not used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two lines here that initializes and open the copy of your destination file

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(destFile);
```

You should remove them. OleDb interaction with the Excel file doesn't need Interop to work.

By the way, when working with these ugly Interop variables I use a simple trick to shorten these names

```
using ExcelLib = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
.....

ExcelLib.Application xlApp = new ExcelLib.Application();
```

Comment: I can't recall what did I use those for... Anyway this certainly solved my issue. Thanks a lot.